# Problems using GridCells msgs in own eclipse project

Tags: ros, messages, eclipse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

i would like to use the GridCells messages defined in common_msgs/nav_msgs in my own project.

Up till now i had a include_directory() statement in my CMakeList.txt file which pointed to the header file defining GridCells, but i wander if i could just add a  onto my manifest.xml and add #include "nav_msgs/GridCells.h" to my code. ( like stated in the tutorial http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/DefiningCustomMessages )

My problem is if i do that compilation still fails saying that GridCells.h is not found. What i dont udnerstand about the nav_msgs package is that it doest seems to export any linker cflags for incluing the messages of the package.

So  how am i supposed to use this messages without having to specify the include file by hand?

Regards,
Manuel

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11692/problems-using-gridcells-msgs-in-own-eclipse-project/) by [momus](https://answers.ros.org/users/1285/momus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2011-10-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

the problem was that i am using the eclipse environment for development and build. After chancing CMakeList.txt i forgot to run "cmake Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles" to rebuild the eclipse project files. After doing so, the header file was found and everything compiled fine.

Thank you very much!

---

Originally posted by [momus](https://answers.ros.org/users/1285/momus/) with karma: 41 on 2011-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using `<depend package="nav_msgs">` is the recommended usage. The message headers are exported automatically, so there is no need for explicit linker flags.

Do you have `common_msgs` installed? Is it in your `$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`?

What does `roswtf` say?

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-10-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2